# Can't see video files on memory card

Tags: video, big-sur, exfat, canon

I have an Extreme PRO 64GB SanDisk memory card for my Canon camera. In macOS I can view the pictures I took, but not the videos. They just don't show up in the Finder window but I *can* watch them on the camera.

How can I access the videos?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the correct folder on the card?

Comment: Yes, as @nohillside said, sometimes there are separate folders for photos and videos. If not, see if the videos are at the end of the list of files.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they are not stored in the Camera internal memory (if has one).

Videos are usually much bigger files. What you can try is to open the mounted memory card, switch to List view and select “Calculate sizes” in CMD + J dialog. Sort files by size and dig deeper in the biggest folders until you find the biggest files.

Or try to identify approximate average size of photos and based on that you can try to search for files in the most top folder level of the memory card by pressing CMD + F and with small plus sign button you can add “File Size” criteria with “is greater than” option and put there value you identified or just something like 20 MB.

You may find files that are big but not playable by Quicktime or any video player currently installed on your Mac which means the camera uses its own format that you may need to convert.